# Stored procedure error asking for id to be passed for output

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have this insert statement

```
CREATE PROCEDURE s_Add$Subject 
  (@SubjectName varchar(50),
  @TheSubjectID int OUT)
AS
  INSERT INTO [Subject] (SubjectName)
    VALUES (@SubjectName)
  SET @TheSubjectID = @@IDENTITY
```

I don't remember this ever happening before, but since the output parameter is an output, why is it calling for the id to be passed? Then I tried to make the `@TheSubjectID` as a declared variable and it was throwing an error, I set that as

```
declare @TheSubjectID int out
```

and it caused an error because it said incorrect syntax by int. Oh, and please don't bash me for using `@@IDENTITY` and not `SCOPE_IDENTITY`, I prefer `@@IDENTITY`, and never had any issues. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE s_Add$Subject (
   @SubjectName varchar(50), 
   @TheSubjectID int = NULL OUT)
AS
  INSERT INTO [Subject] (SubjectName)
    VALUES (@SubjectName)
  SET @TheSubjectID = @@IDENTITY
```

Comment: Thanks guys for the answers. This morning when I looked over everything again, and realized that it wasn't the stored procedure that was causing the error, it was an error in my codebehind page. I had forgotten to pass a parameter for the output.